# Query to Check date and time of Last DML done on a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, dml

As per the requirement i need to capture the the last DML operations in tables in complete schema while searching i have noticed two resources

**Resource 1**
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115062/how-to-get-a-last-dml-operation-in-oracle-10g-11g

**Resource 2**
https://oraclebykkbakshi.blogspot.com/2018/04/check-date-and-time-of-last-dml-done-on.html

Among the above i have tried using both the queries

**Query1 - DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS**

```
SELECT TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,INSERTS,UPDATES,DELETES,TIMESTAMP AS LAST_CHANGE
FROM  DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS
WHERE TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP,'DD.MM.YYYY') = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY') 
and table_owner='SCHEMA_NAME'
and table_name in ('MY LIST OF TABLES')
```

Result - it fetched only the results which had fetched only few tables

**Query2 - is very slow**

```
select max(ora_rowscn),SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(max(ora_rowscn)) FROM 'MY LIST OF TABLES'
```

If i check for any tables using query 2 i am getting the below error

**Error Query 2**

```
ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1
08181. 00000 -  "specified number is not a valid system change number"
*Cause:    supplied scn was beyond the bounds of a valid scn.
*Action:   use a valid scn.
```

how to check all the tables in a single go ,since if i need to use query 2 ,how do i list out multiple tables in a single query ?

so my question is which is the correct query to search for ?

or any other better ways to look for ,any suggestions ?

Upon suggestion i have tried running the query

```
SELECT *
  FROM 'TABLE_NAME' t
MINUS
SELECT *
  FROM 'TABLE_NAME'
  AS OF timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' day t
```

AS OF timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' day t - what is the value i have to use here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use

- `AUDIT` clause for an individual schema such as `hr`

  ```
  AUDIT ALL BY hr BY ACCESS;
  AUDIT SELECT TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, INSERT TABLE, DELETE TABLE BY hr BY ACCESS;
  ```

  after connectiong to SYS as admin, in order to capture the DML.

***Or***, alternatively you can create

- some database triggers for some desired tables, of which you need to track the
  DML data in order to retain the log within a customly created new
  table(s).

***Or*** for the current position for querying the previously processed data, you can use

- **Flashback Queries** having

  `AS OF timestamp systimestamp - INTERVAL '<int>' [year|month|day|hour|minute|second]` syntax for an individual table in such a way that

  ```
  SELECT *
    FROM tab t
   WHERE t.id = :v_id
  MINUS
  SELECT *
    FROM tab
    AS OF timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' day t
   WHERE t.id = :v_id;
  ```

  which returns the data of the day before having the same
  hour:minute:second combination with the current time provided the
  value of **undo_retention** DB paremeter is big enough to hold the
  data of the time point in the past. (For this case, the value should
  be *86400*(in second) at least)

Comment: ,Many thanks for various options i have tried using the Flashback queries v_id what is the value i need to put ?

Comment: you're welcome @rakesh , its just a recommendation to filter by `id` column if it exists for your table. You might completely remove the WHERE condition also. Just offered considering to restrict the data in order to fetch faster through a column which has primary key.

Comment: AS OF timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' day t i have tried to input like AS OF timestamp systimestamp - interval '100' day t it's not working ,if want to compare data from 01.08.2020 ?

Comment: Please read the explanation about *undo_retention* @rakesh